# Availbale tools to distribute a build a cross different machines?

Tags: build, build-process, build-automation, gnu-make

I have a Makefile for Gmake to do the build for my C/C++ Projects, I want to distribute the build across different machines to make it faster, right now it takes 6+/- Hours.
I have found about Buildbot, which might be able to do the job, although nothing tested yet.
Is there any other tools available that would not make assumption about the project/code structure, and with minimal to no modification would take a Makefile and distribute the build across different machines?

Answer (score 0):

The most well-known one is [distcc](https://code.google.com/p/distcc/).